# Calling method of concrete class which implemets interface

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface :

```
public interface IHello {}
```

I have 2 classes :

```
public class A : IHello
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class B : IHello
{
}
```

When I make a call to Method1(), I get the following error :

```
public class C
{
    private IHello obj123;
    static void Main() 
    {
        obj123 = new A();
        obj123.Method1();  // Method1 does not exist in IHello
    }
}
```

I understand that obj123 is of type IHello.
I want to do something like (GetTypeof(Ihello)).Method1 exists? Then call

How to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you have `IHello` empty? Let it declare `Method1`

Comment: @Dmitry I have some constraints to not to do that.

Comment: Ok currently i have made this solution but it does not look neat. Any other improvements would be welcome  :   
                if ( obj123 is A)
                {
                    (obj123 as A).Method1();
                }

Comment: If you want good answers you need to explain what those constraints are. using `is A` is certainly possibl. But the best solution for the actual example is to specify the correct type for the field, i.e. `private A obj123`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (obj123 is A a)
{
    a.Method1();
}
```

Please note that this type of selectively casting is often seen as bad OOP design. You should probably not rely on it too much and instead find a design where this isn't neccessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try-cast to `A`, for example with the [`as`-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator):

```
obj123 = new A();
A a = obj123 as A;
a?.Method1(); // if a is null this does nothing
```

The `?` is the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-).

Answer (score 1):

The method declaration needs to be on the interface.  Update your interface like this:

```
public interface IHello  
{
    void Method1();
}
```

Class A and Class B will need to implement Method1() if they are to implement IHello.

You might want clarify what you're trying to achieve.  If Class B shouldn't implement Method1 then either use separate interfaces or declare the variable as:

```
private A obj123;
```